# Specman - How can I finish the test from the test file?

Tags: testing, verification, specman

U have the following extend sequence in the test file:

```
extend MAIN vr_ad_sequence {  
   !sending_byte : bool;
   baud_rate : baud_rate_t;
   cts_en : bit; 

   ......
   ......

      --TX block
      if uart_regs.uartlcr.txe == 1 {
         for i from 1 to bytes_to_send {
            sending_byte = TRUE;
            do SEND_BYTE seq;
           // wait true (not(sending_byte));
            wait[6000];
         };
         out(sys.time, " : All bytes sent!");
      };
   };   
};
```

I want to finish the test after the line `out(sys.time, " : All bytes sent!");`
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always call stop_run() to stop the test immediately.

in case you are using objections, you should drop the objection against "TEST_DONE". this will allow the other drivers to complete as well before the test will be stopped.

see also "stop_run" and "End-of-Test Handling" in the Specman docs.

Comment: where can I find good and helpful explanation regarding the objections?